# Angular component won't display template

Tags: angular, components

I have simple application in angular with one component. This is todo app from tutorial. I wanted to add second component.
I folder app I have now folder new-component1. In this folder I have four files:

[image]

In new-component1.component.ts I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-component1',
  templateUrl: './new-component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-component1.component.css']
})
export class NewComponent1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In new-component1.component.html file I have only one paragraph with sample text that I want to display.
My app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewComponent1Component } from './new-component1/new-component1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewComponent1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

NewComponent1Component is added to declarations. Everythink compiles without error. But when I want to display in index.html data from component:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-new-component1></app-new-component1>
</body>
```

nothing is displayed. Only contents of app-root is displayed. This is first component generated with todo-app. How to display data from my component?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture#components

Comment: you should move your app-new-component-1 inside the template of your main component

Comment: `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` is the one that is getting bootsrapped .. so `<app-root></app-root>` will hold every other component.. place your selector inside `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the `app-new-component1` tag in the `index.html` file, it should go in the `app.component.html` file, for example. You're essentially placing the Angular component outside the Angular application.